# Enforcing shape and dtype when creating an array

Tags: python, numpy

Using numpy 1.24.2, I'm trying to create a very simple array to store 3d coordinates using a dtype made of 3 floats. However, when using this dtype to create an array, `shape` and `dtype` are modified such that I cannot later find if the array hold 3d coordinates based on `dtype` only:

```
>>> dt = np.dtype( (np.float32, 3) )
>>> Z = np.zeros(10, dt)
>>> Z.dtype
dtype('float32')
>>> Z.shape
(10, 3)
>>> Z.view(dt)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Changing the dtype to a subarray type is only supported if the total itemsize is unchanged
```

I understand this shape/dtype combination is equivalent but I wonder if it is possible to ask numpy to keep my dtype instead ? For example, if I use a named dtype (`dt = np.dtype( [("xyz", np.float32, 3)]`) it works as expected, but in my case, I don't want the name.

Comment: I haven't played with your original dtype style, but I think you found the answer.  It has to be named, otherwise you get the 2d 'unstructured' array.  But what's wrong with  just checking the shape?

Comment: I have a np.ndarray derived class (`vec3`) and when internally checking the dtype, it is "lost". Also, the fact that you cannot view an array with the dtype you use to create it is a bit disturbing.

Comment: A dtype with `(itemdtype, shape)` form, is documented on the `dtypes` page, but the example contrasts it  `dt = np.dtype((np.int32, (2,2)))          # 2 x 2 integer sub-array` with a structured array use with named fields.  I don't think such a nameless dtype is of much use.  It's an awkward cross between a structured array and an unstructured one (with separate dtype and shape values).

Comment: What you are trying to use is a `dtype.subdtype`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.subdtype.html   Possible related issue, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17511

Comment: `np.array((1,2,3),dt)` and `np.array([1,2,3],dt)` produce different things, one a (3,) and the other a (3,3).